# DB data lost for each cloudfoundry deploy of grails application

Tags: database, grails, hsqldb, cloud-foundry

I'm developing a grails 2.0.3 application using sts.
I develop and before close sts I usually deploy my application on cloudFoundry.
I'm using HSQLDB and this is DataSource.groovy:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "mcg"
    password = "mcg"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.provider_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            url = "jdbc:h2:file:qhDB"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:file:testDb"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:file:prodDb"
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that each time I deploy my application to cloudfoundry the db becomes empty on the cloud.

Some suggestions?

Comment: You are not using HSQLDB. Your URLs should be `jdbc:hsqldb:file:testDb;shutdown=true` etc. to use HSQLDB

Answer (score 2):

@kenota is correct, but there's the additional risk that the entire instance can crash and get rebuilt, so you would lose all filesystem files, even in /tmp. You're much better off using MySQL or PostgreSQL - both are trivial to use in CloudFoundry and will perform much better. In addition if you have enough traffic that you need multiple web server instances, you will share one database instead of multiple file-based databases that all have different data.

Comment: I tried with    url = "jdbc:h2:file:/tmp/qhDB"  
but I have this error (that I haven't with the old config) SEVERE: Error listenerStart Jul 16, 2012 1:38:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors Jul 16, 2012 1:38:12 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Generate Seed] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stopping Tomcat because the context stopped.


I cannot format my comment...

Comment: Now I want to have persistent db only to store some test data. As soon as this application will become a real one I will move to MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

By doing this:

```
url = "jdbc:h2:file:prodDb"
```

You are asking H2 to use file to store data. But problem is, you are using relative path, so the file will be created in the current working directory of web application, which is usually unpacked web app root.

If you run it on tomcat, the file will be located at: /opt/tomcat7/webapps/app/prodDb If you will redeploy your application with deleting previous one, the database file will be deleted as well.

I think that is exactly what is happening on cloudfoundry.

You should define absolute path to store your database:

```
url = "jdbc:h2:file:/tmp/prodDb"
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve using MySQL service on cloudfoundy.